# Reading images,paragraphs,tables from docx files using apache poi in the order

Tags: apache-poi

I am unable to read some images from docx files using Apache poi with the method getEmbededPictures() of run object.But i am able to read image by using GetAllPictures() from document object.But if i use this method i am unable to read the document in order if the document contains image and then paragraph and so on..Please help me to solve this issue.Finally my question is how can we read docx file in the same order if the docx file contains image,paragrapah,tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know the Image or Picture Location while parsing MS Word Doc in java using apache poi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288104/how-to-know-the-image-or-picture-location-while-parsing-ms-word-doc-in-java-usin)

Comment: I want to know the position of picture in docx files by using XWPF libraries.When i try to read image from a template and copy it to another .docx file image is coming as cross symbol.Also when i try to open .docx file with the image it is displaying message saying document contains unreadable data.Please help me to solve this  issue ASAP.I used document.getAllPictures() to read the image

Comment: See the duplicate question linked above - that's the wrong way to be finding your pictures

Comment: Gagravar,I am using XWPF libraries,not HWPF libraries.Please give me a solution to copy images using XWPF libraries