# how to get a whole content of file using apache-poi?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

I try to read file .docx with help java api Apache POI. I use:

```
public static String view(String nameDoc){
    String text = null;
    try{
        XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(
                new FileInputStream(nameDoc));
        XWPFWordExtractor we = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);
        text = we.getText();
        we.close();
        docx.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return text;
}
```

In this case i get only a text of file, but my file includes a text, table, pictures... How can i get full content of file?

Comment: see my answer , it will work and help you..

Comment: What do you mean by "full content of file"? For example, I can't see how you can get pictures in a text string....

Comment: This answer should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/28304463/1997376

Answer (score 0):

```
String contents = "";

     try {  
         System.out.println("Starting the test");  
         POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("D:/Resume.doc"));  
         HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);  
         WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);  
         OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/test.pdf")); 
         PdfWriter parser = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, file);  
         parser.parse(); 
         PDDocument pdfDocument = parser.getPDDocument(); 
         PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper(); 
         contents = stripper.getText(pdfDocument); 
         pdfDocument.close();

     } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
     }
```

In `contents` you get full content of file.

Comment: it is a docx not a pdf

Comment: it doesn't provide the full content (images, tables.. included) but only the text content

Comment: @NicolasFilotto , for extract image please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063324/extract-image-from-pdf-using-java

Comment: Where is a variable `document`? `PdfWriter parser = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);`
`parser.parse(); ` don't find a method `parse()`

Comment: @Oleg1n its `doc`

Comment: @Oleg1n for extract image, please refer this question ->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063324/extract-image-from-pdf-using-java

Comment: PDFWriter is in com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter?

Comment: `PdfWriter parser = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, file);`- It doesn't compile. "Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument', required: 'com.itextpdf.text.pdf.Document'"